# wpf MVVM flow design for Application with many UserControls

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I've created an application with many UserControls and now I need to call some function from other UserControl ViewModel, my question is how to build the ViewModels hierarchy to have an access for doing this? What is the best design pattern for this?

Let say I have:

MainUserControl which contains
   UserControl_1 and ViewModel_1
      UserControl_1_1 and ViewModel_1_1
   UserControl_2 and ViewModel_2

so now from UserControl_1_1 I need to call some function from ViewModel_2

Any Example how to init all UserControl's DataCOntexts?

UserControl_1_1 is my TaskDetail
UserControl_2 is my Library

in my TaskDetail I have an attachment and after navigate button clicking I need to navigate to my Library usercontrol and select current attachment

Comment: "so now from UserControl_1_1 I need to call some function from ViewModel_2" => no, you need *something to happen* that VM2 is responsible for doing. "I need to call some function from VM2" locks you in a narrow field of view that most likely does not include a good solution to the problem. Tell us more about what's really going on in the application.

Comment: I've added more details hope I've explained clearly

Comment: Sorry, but no. You are facing an architectural issue, and two lines is not enough by far to clearly describe what the architecture needs to accommodate.

Answer (score 0):

For cross view model communication look into the [Event Aggregator pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventAggregator.html) (a version of Pub/Sub).
Each viewmodel takes a reference to the event aggregator and then viewmodel1 can publish a message that viewmodel2 acts on.